# Reversing a power supply with an spdt switch?

Tags: power-supply

I'm currently trying to turn a 12 rpm motor from clockwise to counter clockwise and vice versa, I just wanted to know if it was possible to do with 1 spdt toggle switch, Ideas?

Comment: What else components you have for the same. How are you controlling the switch? Do you have already designed a circuit diagram for it? How is the motor powered? Are you controlling manually or via H bridge / separate controllers?

Comment: Is it a dc motor?

Comment: Use the switch to control a DPDT relay.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a dual supply, use the switch to control the motor *and* a half bridge, or use the switch to control a SPDT relay (or a full H bridge/DPDT relay but in the latter two cases you only need a SPST switch so you are 'wasting' one contact on the switch and replacing it with another contact or transistor(s)).

---

If you have two supplies (eg. a bench supply with +/- outputs) - not likely:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEUCRx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

More likely situation (only one supply available):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvXwEL.png)</sup>

Since SPDT relays are much cheaper and more available than DPDT relays (eg. JS1a type) this would be a better solution if your switch can handle the motor current (and a bit more for the relay).

If you want to add suppression to the motor to minimize contact arcing, connect a bridge rectifier with the 'AC input' terminals across the motor, and the + terminal to the positive supply and the - terminal to ground, as shown above.

Answer (score 4):

In the general case, it takes a DPDT switch to effectively flip two leads:

[image]

If all you have access to are the two wires from the power supply and the two wires to the motor, then no, it can't be done with a SPDT switch.

Answer (score 0):

Using ONLY spdt switch, it's not possible. But, you can using four npn-transistors to build a simple H-bridge circuit to change the polarity of the motor.

Here's a simple circuit to do that.

[image]

Here, S1 is the desired SPDT switch. To make your life easier, you can also use motor drivers like l293d that has two H-bridges built-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can, granted you have a **Bipolar** supply. If this contraption is battery powered then you can form a Bipolar supply by tapping off the centre connection of a series arrangement of two batteries.

[image]